# OpsCenter - How does it communitate with agents?

Tags: cassandra

I would like to know how OpsCenter communicates with its Agents and Cassandra Nodes.

Does it use Thrift? Is JMX required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll base my answer on the latest released version of OpsCenter (1.3).

The main OpsCenter process can communicate with the agents in two ways. It can query the agents over an http rest api that each agent exposes. It uses this to ask the agent basic things about the cassandra node and also to have the agent send jmx commands to the cassandra process.

The other way is using the STOMP protocol. (http://stomp.github.com//) Agents send messages over STOMP to a message queue in OpsCenter. These generally contain details about the cassandra node and metric information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: According to OpsCenter docu it communicates using JMX, but something is missing there. In OpsCenter I need only to configure one Cassandra node (not agent). OpsCenter will automatically obtain from first Cassandra node IP addresses of other agents - it means that OpsCenter also uses the same Gossip as Cassandra itself - Ops Center agents register into Cassanda cluster, right

Comment: My answer was regarding the communication between OpsCenter and the agents. The agents will talk to nodes via JMX. Additionally the main OpsCenter process will communicate with the cluster using thrift. The thrift 'describe_ring' call is how OpsCenter discovers the rest of your cluster. It does not participate in gossip.

Comment: how OpeCenter discovers its agents?

Comment: Once the agents have been installed, they will contact the OpsCenter server and start sending data. OpsCenter does not need to discover them.

Comment: sooooo my understanding of: "install_agent.sh <opscenter_host> <node_listen_address>" was wrong. opscenter_host is the host where OpsCenter service is running and node_listen_address is the connection to cassandra node (JMX) which is being monitored by particular agent. Agent communicates with cassandra node using JMX and agent also communicates actively with OpsCenter using REST protocol (or maybe also JMX)